# SelectListItem com atributos costumizados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Criei um `DropDownList` através do método abaixo:

```
private void PopulateDropDown() {
  //Chamo o método que obtém a lista de clientes da API
  List<Models.Cliente> clientes = new Business.Cliente().Get();

  //Rotorno a lista de clientes para a view
  ViewData["Clientes"] = new SelectList(clientes, "Id", "Nome", "IdGrupoCliente");

}
```

**Classe Cliente:**

```
public class Cliente{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Nome { get; set; }
  public int IdGrupoCliente { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon addon-no-border">
      Selecione o cliente:
    </span>
   @Html.DropDownList("IdCliente", (SelectList)ViewData["Clientes"], new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Preciso criar um **atributo costumizado** nas `options` do meu `select`,  porém não estou sabendo a melhor forma de fazer isso. A minha ideia era adicionar um `data-IdGrupoCliente` como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<select class="form-control" id="IdCliente" name="IdCliente">
   <option value="1" data-IdGrupoCliente="10">Cliente Abc</option>
</select>
```

Comment: E se fizesse um método que fosse inteligente e carregasse a informação de uma classe padrão.?

Comment: Sugeriram sobrescrever o método do `DropDownList ` para prever esse tipo de situação, acho que é mais ou menos o que você quis dizer mas com outro método. Se quiser posta o que você está imaginando é bom ter varias soluções xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa ter em mente que nem tudo pode ou deve ser escrito usando os HTML Helpers, eles servem para dar uma facilitada nas coisas, mas nos casos em que se precisa de mais liberdade é melhor optar não usá-los.

Ao invés de usar um `SelectList`, use uma `List<Cliente>` simples e crie as *options* da *tag* `select` manualmente através de um laço.

Veja um exemplo

<sub>**Cliente.cs**</sub>

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public int IdGrupoCliente { get; set; } 
}
```

<sub>**HomeController.cs**</sub>

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private List<Cliente> _clientes = new List<Cliente>
    {
        new Cliente { Id = 1, Nome = "Julius", IdGrupoCliente = 2 },
        new Cliente { Id = 2, Nome = "Chris", IdGrupoCliente = 1 },
        new Cliente { Id = 3, Nome = "Drew", IdGrupoCliente = 2 },
        new Cliente { Id = 4, Nome = "Tonya", IdGrupoCliente = 1 },
        new Cliente { Id = 5, Nome = "Rochelle", IdGrupoCliente = 2 }
    };

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {           
        ViewData["Clientes"] = _clientes;
        return View();
    }
}
```

<sub>**Index.cshtml**</sub>

```
<div class="container">
   <select class="form-control" name="@Html.NameFor(model => model.IdCliente)" id="@Html.IdFor(model => model.IdCliente)">
      @foreach(var cliente in ViewData["Clientes"] as List<Sample.Cliente>)
      {
          <option data-id-grupo-cliente="@cliente.IdGrupoCliente" value="@cliente.Id">@cliente.Nome
          </option>
      }
   <select>     
</div>
```

[**Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r3L1aI)

Comment: Brooklyn + 1987

Answer (score 2):

A solução que encontrei foi passar a lista de clientes através de um `viewData[]` e criar o `<select>` diretamente na `View`.

```
ViewData["Clientes"] = new Business.Cliente().Get(idDistribuidor);
```

Percorri a lista de clientes com um `for` preenchendo as `<option>` com o atributo costumizado a cada iteração:

```
<div class="panel-body">
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Importacao", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
         <div class="form-group ">
            <div class="input-group">
               <span class="input-group-addon addon-no-border">
                  Selecione o cliente:
               </span>
               <select name="IdCliente" id="IdCliente" class="form-control">
                  <option value="-1">Selecione</option>
                  @{
           System.Collections.Generic.List<InpartSaude.Negociacao.Models.Cliente> clientes = (System.Collections.Generic.List<InpartSaude.Negociacao.Models.Cliente>)ViewData["Clientes"];
                      for (int i = 0; i < clientes.Count; i++) {
                         <option value="@clientes[i].Id" data-IdGrupoCliente="@cliente[i].IdGrupoCliente">
                            @clientes[i].Nome
                         </option>
                      }
                   }
                </select>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 }
</div>
```